# How to set music playback slider in music player

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmusicplayercontroller

i created a music player with previous and next functionality in my app.i want to impliment song playback slider. how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a `UISlider` setting the maxValue to the current playing song duration (in seconds) and the minValue to 0.

Assuming that you're using an `MPMusicPlayerController` use the `currentPlaybackTime` to get the current time of the playing track and use that value to update the slider each second

```
slider.value = musicPlayerController.currentPlaybackTime;
slider.minimumValue = 0;
slider.maximumValue = [musicPlayerController.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:@"MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration"];
```

Comment: Then use currentPlaybackTime property of MPMusicPlayerController to get the current time of the playing track and update it every second using an NSTimer.

Answer (score 8):

```
- (IBAction)slide:(id)sender{

    [musicPlayer setCurrentPlaybackTime: [slider value]];
}

- (void)actualizaSlider{

slider.value = musicPlayer.currentPlaybackTime;
slider.minimumValue = 0;

NSNumber *duration = [self.musicPlayer.nowPlayingItem valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyPlaybackDuration];

float totalTime = [duration floatValue];

slider.maximumValue = totalTime;
```